# Were is exportHelper documentation

Tags: python, add-on

The only resource I found are in the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150932/export-file-dialog-in-blender-2-80), which is very complete but doesn't cover everything. So:

- What is ExportHelper? How does adding it to a class declaration modify the execute method in order to call the file dialog?
- Why is there [no documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.io_utils.html#bpy_extras.io_utils.ExportHelper) about it on doc.blender.org
- What are all the variables related to it (`filename_ext`, `filter_glob`, `use_setting`, and that's all?)
- Where may I found some info about it?

(Additional : [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150932/export-file-dialog-in-blender-2-80) mentioned above indicates to look at `Templates > Python > Operator File Export`, which "Templates" is this reffering to?)

Comment: https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/b964f73e7dc435b8b455b4ffbef7132aaeef1e0d/release/scripts/modules/bpy_extras/io_utils.py#L55

Comment: I'm not so good at python to understand all of it, but I see no option besides `check_existing`?

Comment: I finally found a bit of help here https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-blenders-filebrowser-with-python/ (explaining for example the use of properties). Had to search importHelper instead of export helper