# Export collection and set FBX file name as collection name?

Tags: python, scripting, export, .fbx, collections

How difficult is it to make a selection by collection and set the FBX file name as the collection name?

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.object.apply_all_modifiers()
bpy.ops.object.join()

scn = bpy.context.scene
sel = bpy.context.selected_objects
meshes = [o for o in sel if o.type == 'MESH']

for obj in meshes:
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY')

# bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals() # just flip normals
# bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=True) # or recalculate inside
bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=False) # or recalculate outside

bpy.ops.object.mode_set()
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="../geometry_result/name.fbx", path_mode='RELATIVE', use_selection=True, object_types={'MESH'})
# bpy.ops.ed.undo()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Export all objects of a certain collection

Pretty much straight forward. Just pass `use_active_collection=True` argument when calling [`export_scene.fbx()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html?highlight=export_scene#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx) operator and assemble your filepath using [`Collection.name`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html#bpy.types.Collection):

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(
    filepath=bpy.path.abspath("//{}.fbx".format(C.collection.name)),
    use_active_collection=True
    )
```

Note that all modifiers will be applied by default, no need to do anything.

---

### Export selected objects of a certain collection

If you'd like to **modify the mesh objects** beforehand, you would have to select them anyway so just make sure the objects you want to export are *selected* and pass `use_selection=True` to the [`bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html?highlight=export_scene#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx) operator.

Demo on how export all objects of the *collection in context* having `Cube` in their name:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")

# Get the desired objects of the active collection
mesh_objects = [o for o in C.collection.objects if "Cube" in o.name]
for obj in mesh_objects:
    obj.select_set(True)

# Export the selection
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(
    filepath=bpy.path.abspath("//{}.fbx".format(C.collection.name)),
    use_selection=True
    )
```

Note that you can also pass a [set of object types](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to the operator in order to export certain types of objects: `object_types={'EMPTY', 'CAMERA', 'LIGHT', 'MESH', 'OTHER'}`

---

### Modify and export all mesh objects of a certain collection

As of 2.8x we can enter *Edit Mode* for all selected objects simultaneously, which avoids looping over all the objects as well as switching to *Edit Mode* and *Object Mode* each iteration. Also I'd suggest **do not modify the original meshes**, *duplicate* the objects you want to modify, *edit* and *delete* them.

Demo on how to [duplicate all mesh objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/duplicating-non-primitive-mesh-with-python) of the *active collection*, switch into *Edit Mode*, convert the geometry into triangles, [export the modified geometry to FBX](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169537/exporting-multiple-meshes-individually-at-once) and lastly remove [all temporary objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27235/31447) from the scene:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# Get all mesh objects of the active collection
mesh_objects = [o for o in C.collection.objects if o.type == 'MESH']

# If mesh objects list is not empty
if mesh_objects and C.mode == 'OBJECT':
    
    # Duplicate all mesh objects and get their references
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate({'selected_objects' : mesh_objects})
    mesh_dupes = C.selected_objects
    
    # Set one object of the dupes to the active object 
    C.view_layer.objects.active = mesh_dupes[0]
    # Switch into Edit Mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    # Select all vertices
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    # Convert to tris
    bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY')
    # Switch back to Object Mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
    # Export the modified objects to FBX
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(
        filepath=bpy.path.abspath("//{}.fbx".format(C.collection.name)),
        use_selection=True)
    
    # Delete all duplicates
    bpy.ops.object.delete({"selected_objects" : mesh_dupes})
```

Make sure the desired **collection is active** in the *Outliner* and run the script.

---

If you'd like to turn this script into an operator, have a look into:

- [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui/57332#57332)
- [Exporting multiple meshes individually at once](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169537/exporting-multiple-meshes-individually-at-once)
- [Export File Dialog in Blender 2.80](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150932/export-file-dialog-in-blender-2-80)
- [Batch exporting scene collections or selected objects using glTF-Blender-IO](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168140/batch-exporting-scene-collections-or-selected-objects-using-gltf-blender-io)
- ...

Comment: Many thanks! Now everything works well, my last task is the team Undo, return the geometry to its original state and I will have a dream addon

Comment: I was in a hurry to rejoice, at the output I get a document in which all the geometry from the collection is located, but only the selected one is needed + I have a number of combination and triangulation commands, they began to be partially ignored. 

Perhaps I would be satisfied with such an export
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx('INVOKE_DEFAULT') 

Only a very lacking team UNDO

Comment: @KasAndrr The provided code exports all objects of the *collection in context*. Make sure the collection you'd like to export *is active*, I guess your *Scene Collection* is the active one so the operator will export *all objects*. Recommend take your time, edit your question, explain in detail what else and post your code.

Comment: @KasAndrr: Please consider to accept the answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour