# How to write a script to multiply a mesh and after that export the multiplied meshes to an FBX file

Tags: python, export, geometry-nodes, .fbx

I'm learning to work with blender and also to program with Python. I found an article teaching how to create a maze, multiplying the faces and edges all through Geometry Nodes and carving the walls using Python as below. And I wanted to export this maze to fbx. But when I do this the conventional way I get only the original walls and pillars (meshes) and everything that was done through the Geometry and script is not exported.
I tried to export using a script I found here in this post: [Export collection and set FBX file name](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/230677/export-collection-and-set-fbx-file-name-as-collection-name)

But it did not work.
Has anyone tried this? Would you help me?

This is the code I'm using (and blender file is attached: [maze.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14WXCwdW_0J2_RC4ift0VwGWXVUHgOSzq/view?usp=sharing)):

```
''' select a mesh object and then run this script to turn that object into a maze '''

import bpy, bmesh, random, os

active = bpy.context.active_object

if active.type != 'MESH':
    raise Exception("Active object must be a mesh object")

# make sure the active object has the maze nodes modifier
maze_nodes = bpy.data.node_groups['Maze']
maze_modifier = None
for modifier in active.modifiers:
    if modifier.type == 'NODES' and modifier.node_group == maze_nodes:
        maze_modifier = modifier
        break
if not maze_modifier:
    maze_modifier = active.modifiers.new('Maze', 'NODES')
    maze_modifier.node_group = bpy.data.node_groups['Maze']
    for i in range(len(active.modifiers) - 1):
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up(modifier=maze_modifier.name)
        

# get the active mesh and make sure it has the 'closed' attribute
mesh = active.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
closed = mesh.attributes.get('closed')
if not closed:
    closed = mesh.attributes.new(name='closed', type='BOOLEAN', domain='EDGE')
    closed.name = 'closed'

# reset the maze by closing all the edges
for e in bm.edges:
    setattr(closed.data[e.index], 'value', True)

# randomly choose a cell to start carving out the maze from
# current_cell = random.choice(list(bm.faces))
current_cell = list(bm.faces)[255]
visited = [current_cell]
stack = [current_cell]

# loop until the entire maze has been carved out
while len(stack) > 0:
    current_cell = stack.pop()
    
    # get a list of unvisited neighbors to the current cell
    unvisited_neighbors = []
    for edge in current_cell.edges:
        for neighbor in edge.link_faces:
            if neighbor != current_cell and neighbor not in visited:
                unvisited_neighbors.append(neighbor)
                
    # if there are any unvisited neighbors then randomly choose one to visit
    if len(unvisited_neighbors) > 0:
        stack.append(current_cell)
        chosen_neighbor = random.choice(unvisited_neighbors)
        visited.append(chosen_neighbor)
        stack.append(chosen_neighbor)
        
        # open all the edges between the current cell and the chosen neighbor
        for edge in current_cell.edges:
            if edge in chosen_neighbor.edges:
                setattr(closed.data[edge.index], 'value', False)

# update the mesh so that the maze is visible immediately
setattr(closed.data[0], 'value', False)
setattr(closed.data[2], 'value', False)

mesh.update()

C = bpy.context

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(
    filepath=bpy.path.abspath("//{}.fbx".format(C.collection.name)),
    use_active_collection=True
    )
```

Comment: After a long chat with ChatGPT I finally got a solution to this problem. I was able to export the objects generated by Geometry and modified by the Python script. As soon as I have time, I'll post the solution with details and screenshots here.